# how to read .shp files in R Tool

Tags: r

[link for the .shp file dataset](http://web1.sph.emory.edu/users/lwaller/ch9index.htm)

I want to read a .shp file from R tool, am using the following script:

```
>scot_LL<-readOGR("C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Desktop/scotlip/lip cancer/New Scot/scot.shp","scot"),
```

but when I run the script, am getting the below errors:

```
>Error in file(paste(DSN, .Platform$file.sep, layer, ".dbf", sep = ""),  <br/>: 
  cannot open the connection<br/>: 
In addition: Warning message:<br/>: 
In file(paste(DSN, .Platform$file.sep, layer, ".dbf", sep = ""),  :<br/>: 
  cannot open file 'C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Desktop/scotlip/lip cancer/New Scot/scot.dbf': No such file or directory
```

Can you please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using the `maptools` package:

```
library(maptools)

scot_mp <- readShapeSpatial('C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Desktop/scotlip/lip cancer/New Scot/scot.shp')

proj4string(scot_mp) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84" # specify projection

plot(scot_mp)
```

and the result:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Solution using the `rgdal` package:

```
scot_mp <- readOGR('C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Desktop/scotlip/lip cancer/New Scot', 'scot')
```

The first argument should not necessary contain the name of shape file, but the main problem seems to be that at least the `dbf` file is not in your folder, all of these are needed and should be in the same folder: `scot.shp, scot.dbf, scot.shx`. After that it proceeds as the other solution:

```
proj4string(scot_mp) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
plot(scot_mp)
```

Comment: >scot_mp <- readShapeSpatial('C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Desktop/scotlip/lip cancer/new scot1/scot.shp')
>Error in getinfo.shape(fn) : Error opening SHP file

Comment: @vinoradha I guess that the other two files (`scot.dbf, scot.shx`) are not in your folder.